# How can a Russian writer get his work translated into English?

Tags: publishing, translation

There is a famous Russian writer named [Yuriy Mukhin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yury_Ignatyevich_Mukhin). He writes books about Stalin and about alternative economic system. All his books are in Russian and have never been translated into other languages. He doesn't know English.

Can you describe plan in steps how can he publish his books in not-russian publishing house without leaving Russia?

How can he get his books translated into English? How does he go about hiring a translator? What publishing houses could handle the translation for him? What would translation typically cost? What kind of royalties or payments does an author receive for a translated work? How does he find and contact a publishing house?

Comment: Rustam: Welcome to Writers SE. I have heavily rewritten your question into more native English (your post was understandable, but I smoothed it out). Please let me know if I changed the meaning of anything when editing. You don't have to worry about paper vs. e-books.

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum Thanks, I restored part about algorithm - because it is main part of question.

Comment: What is your definition of "algorithm"? To a native speaker, that is a specific term for solving a mathematical problem; it doesn't make sense in context here. Do you mean "method" or "plan"?

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum I mean algorithm as the exact sequence of actions (in Russian it also means something more scientific but not only in math) with big count of things like "if publisher can not do something -> then do something another" rather than just a plan.

Comment: In English that concept is "plan" or "detailed plan." "Algorithm" in English is generally limited to math.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum And computing.

Comment: @JAB yes, of course, and computing. :)

Answer (score 4):

If he's been already published in Russia, his publisher should be able to handle it - offer his book on a book fair (Frankfurt Book Fair comes to mind), make a deal with foreign publisher, find a good translator (preferably English translator, not Russian)...

If the author does not want to use publisher (maybe he has way too much free time on his hands :)), the best way would find some foreign publishing house who might be interested in his books (perhaps he specializes on similar books or Russian authors) and send him an email with the offer - whether he would like to publish his books, possibly include some excerpts, manuscript, etc.

Before doing that, he might want to buy some book about creative writing, where the process of communication with publishing house is usually described in detail. Western authors are very good at "selling" themselves, eastern authors - not so much (applies even here in CZ).

I wouldn't worry about translation and royalties, especially at this stage - these are publisher's concerns.

Comment: I think contacting with other publisher through his current russian publisher will left author without money. Because russian publishing houses are very greedy. As example, one friend has published 3D MAX book without any starting money. For all book he get for all time about 1000$. He worked for book about 2 months. Book is published until now.

Comment: Can you post main publishing houses names that publish books at political themes?

Comment: Also can you post here some selling book titles?

Comment: I could, but it's way too specific (and requires considerable effort). Let's keep this question general: "How can a foreign writer approach English market".

Comment: Is this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English-language_book_publishing_companies actual?